# Prevent IIS from starting application before previous instance has been shut down during restart

Tags: iis

Sometimes when IIS restarts the app pool it will start a new instance of my application before the previous instance is shut down completely. This causes me alot of problem so i wonder what i can do about it.

The course of action goes something like this. (spanning about 20 seconds)

1. Application is running, let's call this instance A.
2. Restart initializes
3. A new instance is started, let's call this B (Logged by Application_Start)
4. Incomming request is processed by instance B, this invalidates all data A has cached.
5. Timer on instance A is triggered, assumes its cache is valid and writes something invalid into the persistant storage.
6. Instance A is shut down (logged by Application_End)

Preferable i would like to disable the above behavior completely, IIS should only allow one instance. If not possible, can i in my code detect if other instances is alread running and then wait for it to quit inside application_start? If not possible, what is the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Disable overlapped recycling:

> "In an overlapped recycling scenario,
>   the process targeted for a recycle
>   continues to process all remaining
>   requests while a replacement worker
>   process is created simultaneously. The
>   new process is started before the old
>   worker process stops, and requests are
>   then directed to the new process. This
>   design prevents delays in service,
>   since the old process continues to
>   accept requests until the new process
>   has initialized successfully, and is
>   instructed to shut down only after the
>   new process is ready to handle
>   requests."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Unless you have a valid justification, fix your app instead of changing IIS settings. Overlapped recycling does give better user experience.